# VS Code No Module Found Error - Need help running PySpark code locally

Tags: visual-studio-code, pyspark, pycharm

I've been trying to switch over from PyCharm to VS Code full time, and while I've figured out most things, I'm having a hell of a time trying to run Spark jobs locally (OS X). As far as I can tell I have set up the same configuration (virtualenv and environment variables) as I had working on PyCharm. Here's the configuration I've got on VS Code (defined in `launch.json`):

```
        {
            "name": "Python: spark sql query (local)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/scripts/my_script.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "args": [
                .
                .
                .
            ],
            "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
                "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2"
              },
            "env": {
                "PYTHONUNBUFFERED": "1",
                "APP_NAME": "Local Script",
                "LOGFILE": "output.log",
                "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2",
                "JAVA_HOME": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/"
            }
        },
```

When I run this I just get `ModuleNotFound` errors even though I haven't changed any other piece of code from what was working in PyCharm. Any ideas for me to try?

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/evan***/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/Users/evan***/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 444, in main
    run()
  File "/Users/evan***/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.9.1191016588/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 285, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target_as_str, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/evan***/px_seed_model/scripts/sql_query.py", line 10, in <module>
    from model import SparkModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

Comment: can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: @hprakash Done!

Comment: i suspect the virtualenv is not loaded, i haven't worked on the VSCode, but looking at the launch.json file, i don't see anything about virtualenv, is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was to add `PYTHONPATH` to the `env` dict:

```
    "env": {
        "PYTHONUNBUFFERED": "1",
        "APP_NAME": "Local Script",
        "LOGFILE": "output.log",
        "SPARK_HOME": "/usr/local/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2",
        "JAVA_HOME": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/",
        "PYTHONPATH": "/path/to/project/root:$PYTHONPATH"
    }
```

I believe this is equivalent to checking the box `Add content roots to PYTHONPATH` in PyCharm.